# Laravel: Can't delete data in one column

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I have an API where in it adds PDF to a lesson and also deletes the PDF independently. In my code, what happens is that it deletes the whole row of the ID of the PDF I wanted to delete. What I wanted to do is to make the 'lesson_pdf' empty via delete method.

Here is my controller:

```
public function DeletePDF($id)
{

    $lesson = LessonPDF::find($id);
    if(is_null($lesson)){
        return response()->json('Record not found!', 401);
    }
    $lesson->delete();

    return response('PDF Deleted', 200);

}
```

My LessonPDF Model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class LessonPDF extends Model
{
    public $table = "lesson";
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'lesson_pdf',
    ];

    // protected $guarded = [];
}
```

My API route:

```
Route::delete('pdf-delete/{id}',[LessonPDFController::class,'DeletePDF']);
```

Any suggestions and ideas where I got it wrong will be really appreciated. TIA

Comment: Let me ask, you want to save `lesson_pdf` empty (`null`) instead of literally deleting the row ?

Comment: I want to delete the PDF column only using its lesson ID but what happens in my code, it delete the whole row or data of that ID.

Comment: `delete` will run a normal `SQL` delete, hence you are literally going to delete the row or rows that match... You just want to do `$lesson->lesson_pdf = null;` and then `$lesson->save();`, or `$lesson->update(['lesson_pdf' => null]);`, but your `lesson_pdf` column must be `nullable`, did you write that in your `migration` ?

Comment: Oh I see. Yes, my lesson_pdf is nullable. So I just have to use the update into null, which is a POST method?

Comment: So the only way I delete the column is by using the update=>null POST method?

Comment: it doesn't matter if it is `POST`, `PUT`, `GET` or whatever, you just have to call any of `save` (previously updating the field to `null`, or using `update`)

Comment: alright, I will note this. thank you for the clarifications man!

Comment: do you also have an idea on how to delete the pdf in the storage when I delete the pdf or make it null via api?

Comment: no, I don't. I did not use files enough to help you with it, but it should be pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @matiaslauriti said already in the comments. you just need to update the field to null if was nullable in your migration file.

To delete the file, if the lesson_pdf column contains the exact name of the file,
you can do

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

Storage::delete('lesson_pdf.pdf');
```

Ideally, you want to delete the file before you update the field to null. so you'd do something like

```
public function DeletePDF($id)
{

    $lesson = LessonPDF::find($id);
    if(is_null($lesson)){
        return response()->json('Record not found!', 401);
    }
    Storage::delete($lesson->lesson_pdf);
    $lesson->lesson_pdf = null;
    $lesson->save();
    
    return response('PDF Deleted', 200);

}
```

You can also do an if statement to check If it was deleted before you you run the DB update and the return response. you can throw an error if it didn't. That way you are sure it always deleted.

[Read here on laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#deleting-files) to get more insight

Comment: Do you know how I can also delete it in my file storage? I tried the `Storage::delete($lesson->lesson_pdf);` but it is still inside the folder public\uploads\

Comment: It is a hashed file btw